# Increment the vector value as long as the row number

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation, tidy

I have 2 datasets that I would like to merge. But before that, I would like to increment ID as `tail(df1$ID, n=1) + 1` as long as the last row of the `df2`

```
 df1 <- data_frame(ID = c(1:4), valueA = seq(0.1,0.4,0.1), Category= "Apples" )
df2 <- data_frame(ID = "I NEED TO DEFINE", valueA = seq(0.1,0.4,0.1),  Category= "Apples2")


tail(df1$ID, n=1)
```

Expected Answer

```
 ID ValueA Category
     1    0.1 Apples  
     2    0.2 Apples  
     3    0.3 Apples  
     4    0.4 Apples  
     5    0.1 Apples2 
     6    0.2 Apples2 
     7    0.3 Apples2 
     8    0.4 Apples2
```

How to get around this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're 90% of the way there! Define `end` as the ID value for the last row of `df1`, and increment that with `:`:

```
end <- tail(df1$ID, n=1)
df2$ID <- (end+1):(end+nrow(df2))
bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

Which gave me exactly your expected output.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `bind_rows`:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2 %>% 
            mutate(ID = nrow(df1)+row_number()))

     ID valueA Category
  <int>  <dbl> <chr>   
1     1    0.1 Apples  
2     2    0.2 Apples  
3     3    0.3 Apples  
4     4    0.4 Apples  
5     5    0.1 Apples2 
6     6    0.2 Apples2 
7     7    0.3 Apples2 
8     8    0.4 Apples2
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach may be to sequence the ID in `df2` then use `rbind`:

```
df2$ID <- (nrow(df1) + 1):(nrow(df1) + nrow(df2))

rbind(df1, df2)
```

Output:

```
     ID valueA Category
  <int>  <dbl> <chr>   
1     1    0.1 Apples  
2     2    0.2 Apples  
3     3    0.3 Apples  
4     4    0.4 Apples  
5     5    0.1 Apples2 
6     6    0.2 Apples2 
7     7    0.3 Apples2 
8     8    0.4 Apples2
```